# how to show notification in action bar when user has internet connectivity like facebook without using GCM?

Tags: android, facebook, notifications

This is my Manifestfile

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my Service file

```
package com.example.dmaharjan.myApp;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private int numMessagesOne = 0;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        mBuilder.setContentTitle("title");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Notification Details go here");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

        // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives
        mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of the app to Home page
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        //can only be used once
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // pass the Notification object to the system
        myNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

This is my receiver file

```
package com.example.dmaharjan.myApp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean status = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(isInternetConnected(context)) {
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, 1000, pi);
        }
    }
    boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

To get notification I have to switch off and on but i want to get the notification when I am connected to the internet >> How to acquire it?Like the social media apps does when ever I am connected to the internet it send mes notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver to get notify that internet state is changed
user below code in manifest for BroadcastReceiver

```
<receiver android:name=".offlineAccessUtility.OfflineHandlingReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <!-- <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" /> -->
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

and to show notification you can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityToLaunch.class);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification);
mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
String msg = "Yes! I did it."
mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
mNotifyManager.notify(notificationType, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This didnt work because the notification is coming even there is no internet connection. What am I missing here??

Comment: You need to handle it youself that if there is no internet connection. Then do not call the show notification function.